# Write byte to stringstream

Tags: c++

I need to write byte 0xEB to stringstream. I have decided to do this in two ways:

```
char * f = "\XEB"; 
char  j  = 0xEB;

std::stringstream ss;
ss.write(&j,1);
ss.write(f,1);

wcout<<ss.str().c_str();
```

In console output I have two different strange characters. Why they are different?

Comment: you can use `ss.put('\xEB');`

Comment: `\XEB` is an invalid sequence. I guess you meant `\xEB`.